# Working Magento 1.4.1.0 and changing Mysql from 5.1 to 5.5

Tags: mysql

I have a working stable Magento 1.4.1.0 community website using Mysql 5.1 for many years now with no problems.

If I upgrade Mysql to 5.5 will I have problems with my Magento 1.4.1.0 website? Or should I just stay with Mysql 5.1 and not take a chance of ruining a working stable website?

I know that Mysql 5.1 default engine is MyISam and Mysql 5.5 the default engine is InnoDB. Will this cause problems?

I looked at my present Magento 1.4.1.0 datbase and all but 3 items are TYPE InnoDB, but the default engine is MyISam.

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should not be a foreseen problem with the upgrade:

- http://magento.com/resources/previous-magento-system-requirements
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html

Also consider [Percona](http://www.percona.com/) as an alternate, Percona has some nice InnoDB optimizations and tools.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will be updating to MySql 5.5 and let you know how it goes!

Comment: Update to MySql 5.5 completed and Magento 1.4.1.0 is working perfectly!!  THANKS!!